# Setting up an FTP server without a dedicated IP

Tags: file, file-upload, ftp, file-transfer, resume-download

I'm not sure if this is the best SE site for this question but here goes.

I am looking to implement a simple and easy to use file transfer solution such that people can upload/download files with resume support to our office server (which does not have a static IP address).

So far, I have come across free FTP servers (such as [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server)) and free DNS routing services (such as [dyn](http://dyn.com)) that allow this but I am sure there are simpler solutions out there.

Commercial solutions are welcome as long as non-technical people can administer them.

**UPDATE**: The data transfer per day is around 10GB and although Dropbox is fine for personal use, I'd rather use a more robust application that allows more control and acceleration. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: forget about ftp.  use a shared dropbox of which there are many avaialable.

Comment: Depending on the nature of your requirements the solution that you found my be better or worse than the one suggested by "ddyer" above.  As a rule of thumb - if you intend to allow uploads/downloads of multi-GB files than go with your option, otherwise check the alternative.

Comment: Since you say that commercial recommendations are OK, I hope you don't mine me mentioning FileCatalyst, made by the company I work for. Resume/Retry, verification, acceleration; it's made with fast large file transfer in mind. You would still need to resolve traffic to the office machine, though, so you'd need the dynamic DNS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have two different problems.

- lack of a permanent ip address. This is solced by free dynamic dns services.
- second: resumable tranfer. Ftp is Not o good one.

You should try google drvie or dropbox